# Connecting to a function with arguments

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I'm working on a user interface with PyQt and have finally figured out how to make multiple display options possible (user clicks on a radio button, a signal is saved, and depending on that signal a different function runs when the user hits "display"). I am running into this error message, however:

```
TypeError: connect() slot argument should be a callable or a signal, not 'NoneType'
```

And I think it has to do with the fact that I'm passing functions with arguments into the "connect" method. Here's the chunk of code I'm looking at, in a nutshell:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import myFunctions


try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_ROIGUI(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

def setupUi(self, ROIGUI):
    #sets up radio buttons and display button in AnalyzeDisplay tab
    #i can post more if needed but I haven't messed with it much

    self.buttonGroup = QtGui.QButtonGroup(self.AnalyzeDisplay)
    self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.radiobutton1,1)
    self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.radiobutton2,2)

def retranslateUi(self, ROIGUI):
    self.Display.clicked.connect(self.readSignal)

def readSignal(self):
    signal = self.buttonGroup.checkedId()
    arg1,arg2=myFunctions.loadData()

    if signal == -1:
        print("No option selected")
    elif signal == 1: 
        self.ROITotalActivity.clicked.connect(lambda: myFunctions.function1(arg1,arg2))          
    elif signal == 2:
        self.ROITimeVActivity.clicked.connect(lambda: myFunctions.function2(arg1))
```

The "readSignal" function is called after the "Display" button has been selected, and the signal is obtained from a button group. The interesting thing is that the specified functions (function1 and function2) appear to run even though I get the error message. I've read that the lambda method can be used to solve this:

```
self.ROITimeVActivity.clicked.connect(lambda: self.function2(deltaPix))
```

But something is going wrong when I try to implement it. Although I don't get the error message when I do this, something in the connection/signaling gets messed up - instead of running when I click the radio button and then the display button, the function I want only runs when I click radio button--> display button--> radio button.

ETA: It essentially looks like this:

[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3obD.jpg)

Without lambda, the functions run after choosing a radio button and clicking display, but I get the above error message. With lambda, I do not get an error message, but I have to click a radio button, the display button, and the radio button again to get the function to run.

Thoughts? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would really help if you provided a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example.  We can't take your code above and actually run anything to see the issue you're having, so it's mostly educated guesses at this point.  Does capturing the `deltaPix` variable in the lambda solve your issue?  eg. `self.ROITimeVActivity.clicked.connect(lambda dp=deltaPix: self.function2(dp))`

Comment: What are `ROITotalActivity` and `ROITimeVActivity`, and why are you trying to connect a new signal handler to them every time the display button is clicked? Do you want those handlers to run when the display button itself is clicked, or only when those other buttons are clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> The interesting thing is that the specified functions (function1 and
>   function2) appear to run even though I get the error message.

Nothing surprising about that -- you're **calling** one of those functions right here, and passing that function's **result** (no doubt the `None` you get error messaged about) to `connect` -- that's *always*, in Python, the meaning of

```
a(b(c))
```

for any callables `b` and `a`: it means "call `b` with argument `c` and pass its result as the single argument of `a`.

Now when you use, instead,

```
a(lambda: b(c))
```

you're asking for a 100%-different semantics -- passing as `a`'s single argument **a function** that, **when later called** (w/o arguments), will then "call `b` with argument `c`".

`functools.partial(b, c)`, by the way, is an arguably more elegant approach then `lambda` -- but produces exactly the same semantics.

As for why this isn't fixing everything for you -- I don't know: the code you show, amended with `lambda`, **should** be fine -- if everything else in the vast amount of code you **don't** show was absolutely perfect.  So I suspect the latter condition doesn't hold.  Can you make a simplified-to-the-bone but complete example that exhibits the bug you still observe (once the `lambda` fix is applied)...?